# Is a 1 hour connection sufficient from MAD, Norwegian to Delta at LAX?

Tags: us-citizens, short-connections, lax

Is a 1 hour connection sufficient from MAD, Norwegian to Delta at LAX? We will be traveling from Madrid back to the US, through customs with no checked baggage.

Comment: As usual, it this on a single ticket (doesn’t seem likely with Norwegian and Delta, does it?) or on separate tickets? What is your citizenship and/or immigration status in the US?

Comment: Where will you be flying from? If your origin is in the Schengen area, you'll have to go through passport control in Madrid.

Comment: My general rule of thumb for separate tickets is 4 hours minimum, 6 hours if immigration/customs check is required.

Comment: I think some of the edits to the question made assumptions that may be incorrect. There IS a Norwegian flight from MAD to LAX, so the connection OP is asking about may very well be in LAX, not MAD.

Comment: @jcaron Yes, could be so. Until the OP returns, we don't know.

Comment: Delta do NOT fly MAD-LAX, but Norwegian do, so the edits made by @DavidSupportsMonica are incorrect and completely changed the question :(  I also deleted a fairly complete answer as a result of this incorrect modification...

Comment: @Doc Wasn't trying to change anything, your reversion is fine with me. I still find the OP's wording mysterious: what's the itinerary? Where's the layover?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica my edit was just a revert.  Itinerary is seemingly MAD-LAX on Norewgian, then LAX-??? on DL

Comment: If so, the OP will arrive at TBIT (the LAX International Terminal), and have to go through Immigration and Customs. If the next flight on Delta is domestic, then the OP will probably have to change terminals at LAX. On separate tickets, I would not undertake such a short connection.

Answer (score 4):

Norwegian is a super discount airline, that does not have any partner alliances or codeshares. **So I have a feeling these are separate tickets**.

That's the bad thing.  You need to consult with whoever sells those tickets if *they* offer some sort of connection insurance.  But without something like that, Norwegian is simply not responsible for the *knock-on* effects of a mildly late arrival.

Delta owes you nothing if you miss the flight. You didn't show up, and there's no way to make this Norwegian's fault.  Norwegian doesn't owe you any money for knock-on effects of a (mildly) late arrival.  That's the difference between thru-ticketing and separate ticketing.

You can throw yourself on Delta's mercy; sometimes airlines have "flat tire" rules e.g. if you miss a flight through no fault of your own. However, this kinda would be your fault, booking such a very tight connection.

Comment: I think that third paragraph, end of the second sentence, should be "...there's no way to make this _Delta's_ fault."

Comment: At international airports, [Delta asks passengers to be at the gate 45 minutes before departure](https://www.delta.com/us/en/check-in-security/check-in-time-requirements/international-check-in). Even if the first flight arrives on time, and the two gates are close together, that is practically impossible timing.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica it's right. I'm not repeating the point.